# publish condition not met: Icon image is missing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, icons, manifest.json

I have a chrome extension that has been working since forever.
Every couple of weeks I upload a new version, always in the same manner.
The version I bump each time.

The entire publishing process is automatic using the web store API.
This has always worked, but since today it fails.

The endpoint https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/webstore_api/items/publish
returns now:

```
{
   "error":{
      "code":400,
      "message":"Publish condition not met: Icon image is missing.",
      "errors":[
         {
            "message":"Publish condition not met: Icon image is missing.",
            "domain":"chromewebstore.access",
            "reason":"badRequest"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Which is weird, as nothing has changed recently to the icons.

They are listed nicely in the manifest.json file:

```
"icons": {
  "16": "icons/favicon-16x16.png",
  "32": "icons/favicon-32x32.png",
  "48": "icons/favicon-48x48.png",
  "128": "icons/favicon-128x128.png"
}
```

icons being a directory in the extension's root directory. This setup hasn't changed since forever.
Prior to publishing I uploaded (as always) successfully the zip folder (as documented and as how it always has been and worked).

Can someone help me explain why this suddenly fails? I cannot check for more info via the webstore API as the developer access to that web UI
is currently on vacation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer that has credentials came back last Monday, who is the only one who can access the actual webstore. Via that UI he discovered an image was missing that could only be uploaded via there. Once that was done we could upload our zip artefact and publish using our automated pipeline as once before....

Since the new webstore version things have become pretty unstable with outdated documentation...

Anyhow, problems are fixed for us...